# В DataBinding ViewModel знает о View?

Tags: android, android-data-binding

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по этой картинке - View Model знает о View, я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewModel не знает о View.

Вы, создав экземпляр ViewModel, даёте ссылку на него вьюхе (фрагмент, активити, etc). View передаёт во ViewModel данные, берёт из неё данные и вызывает методы оной.

DataBinding работает аналогично - вы объявляете в разметке какой класс, наследующий ViewModel используется в разметке и потом явно из View передаёте экземпляр ViewModel в разметку.

Answer (score 2):

ViewModel не знает про View напрямую. Между ними есть прослойка Data Binding mapper-а, как собственно на картинке и показано.

Есть два сценария использования databinding-а:

1. Односторонний dataBinding: Просто привязать liveData или [observable](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability) из viewModel к UI-ному компоненту. Например, отображение кнопки(visibility) на UI по состоянию булевской liveData из viewModel
2. Двухсторонний dataBinding: Использовать [observable](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability) филды или написать свой [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) для связи. Например, используется для решений задач с вводом текста из EditText, так чтобы изменение значения филда сразу обновляли значение в EditText и на оборот или же написать свой binding adapter, чтобы сразу отобразить список из viewModel в recyclerView и тд.

Но я бы не рекомендовал его использовать, особенно в рамках большого проекта. Магии в нём нет. Databinding генерирует довольно много кода из-за чего время сборки проекта увеличится. На маленьких проектах в 3-5 простых вьюх думаю можно побаловаться.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, я им не пользуюсь и не собираюсь пользоваться, на собеседованиях просто часто спрашивают работал ли я с DataBinding. Не понимаю, почему кто то на больших проектах его использует у себя, есть Compos(уже в релизе) и ViewBinding. Можете объяснить, пожалуйста, зачем его берут в большие проекты?

Comment: В legacy коде может используют data binding - такой вариант наиболее распространённый, потому что как только data binding для андроида появился, на волне хайпа все его использовали. Чуть позже когда view binding нормально начал себя чувствовать переехали на него, но не все могли себе позволить столько времени для переписывания.

Data binding - даёт иллюзорный комфорт, потому что вернувшись к такому коду спустя год, будите проклинать того кто это написал), особенно если какие-то условия выносить в xml